# Is NumberInt signed in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/shell-types/#numberint) have that much to say about NumberInt

> By default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values. The mongo shell provides the NumberInt() constructor to explicitly specify 32-bit integers.

Which doesn't specify if they are signed or not, ie; if they can handle negative numbers.

I'm about to find out real soon, but for further reference I thought this question might help others find out quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `NumberInt` supports negative values. In the mongo shell:

```
> x = NumberInt(-10)
NumberInt(-10)
```